# An first integral of nonlinear differential equation as like forced pendulum nonlinear diff. eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm trying to face this nonlinear differential equation:

$$ y''(x)+\omega^2\sin\,y(x)=a\,x \,\;(1)$$

and I'm interested to found the solution of $ y'(x)$ (an first integral)

The homogeneous part of previous one ode is like a nonlinear free (non forced) pendulum diff. eq. :
$$ \theta''+\omega^2\sin\theta=0$$
Then, the ode that i'm trying to solve it's similar to forced pendulum differential equations.

The first integral of homogeneous solution of (1) it's easy to solve :
$$\frac{(y'(x))^2}{2}-\omega^2\cos \,y=\mathrm{const}$$

But, is there a solution for fist integral of (1) in a case of forcing of the type $f(x)=a\,x$ or otherwise?

Comment: What do you consider the "trend" of $y'$ (or $y$)? Do you mean something like a linear function where the remainder is a periodic function and some small perturbation?

Comment: No you are right, I had expressed myself badly.I want found y'(x). I corrected the text.

Answer (score 1):

For large $x$ the right side is large, while the $\omega^2 \sin(y)$ term is bounded.  Thus it may be useful to consider this differential equation as a perturbation of $y'' = ax$.
We can write $$ y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \omega^{2k} y_k(x)$$
where $$\eqalign{y_0(x) &= y(0) + y'(0) x + a x^3/6\cr
      y_1(x) &= - \int_0^x dt \int_0^t ds\; \sin(y_0(s))\cr
y_2(x) &= - \int_0^x dt \int_0^t ds\; y_1(s) \cos(y_0(s))\cr 
\text{etc}}$$

I suspect that each $y_k$ for $k \ge 1$ will be asymptotic to some straight line as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I can't use the approssimation for large value of x, or in general of the forced term, in this case. But you proposal is very interesting for many other cases. Very thanks !